# Finding the implementation of a binding in WPF xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know WPF much at all, but I have this piece of xaml which has the following:

```
<Button.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Endcommand}" />
</Button.InputBindings>
```

A search of the whole project finds the following:

```
public ICommand Endcommand { get; set; }

Endcommand = new ViewModels.DelegateCommand(o => DoEnd());
```

in two seperate files.

The DoEnd is also in both files.

How do I find out which one is actually being bound to.  In short I have already figured this out by trial and error, but was hoping for a better solution for the future.

If I try to Peek definition in the xaml file, nothing happens and if I try to Go to definition I get an error saying "Cannot navigate to definition".

If I try "Find all references" in either of the other two files, I only get what is in the same file.

Comment: you need to find where DataContext of View is assigned - by usages of View

Comment: @ASh where do I find that?

Comment: by usages of View across the project: something like View.DataContext = someViewModel. or it can be set via View constructor

Comment: @ASh So it seems like it is a constructor, but it is being accessed in a number of places.  But do I assume that the file (view model) with the same name is the one that it is bound to? (eg ...View.xaml bound to ...ViewModel.cs)

Comment: it *might be* in some MVVM frameworks, which have such convention, but generally WPF doesn't impose any naming pattern for views and their dataContext

Comment: This is not only WPF but MVVM as well. View model is DataContext of a selected view. Binding is an abstraction level to separate click events from implementation, unlike cave man WinForms. If you see a Command property that always expects a Binding to an ICommand implementation. Why you see it in 2 places is because base class defines the ICommand and inheriting class implements it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure at design time what is `DataContext`, because it also can be changed at run time. I would just write for the `Button` where bindings are:

```
<Button Content="{Binding}"/>
```

So I will get the `Object.ToString()` value of the `DataContext` like a `YourNammespace.YourClass`

Comment: I fear this has to be the correct answer.  You'd have thought there would have been a better way.  This doesn't score points for WPF in my book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the live visual tree to see what the datacontext is.

Run your app in debug.

Choose Debug > Windows > Live Visual tree.

Select whatever your view is in the treeview.

Right click and choose properties.

Which should give you another window Live Property Explorer. I think by default that appears on the right over

There's a Datacontext property, amongst others.

This isn't as good as Snoop IMO but you pretty much need to use tools like this if you do any substantial wpf development. Snoop is a free download.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run this in debug mode as it is a dll that gets added to something else where I do not have control to do things like step through the code.  I sorely wish I could.

Answer (score 0):

if the button has been assigned a DataContext then Visual Studio will discover its type's information.

if this is our view model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public ICommand SomeCommand { get; set; }
}
```

and this is our MainWindow where we set the button's data context:

```
<Window
    x:Class="SO60507853.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO60507853"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button>
            <Button.DataContext>
                <local:SomeViewModel />
            </Button.DataContext>
            <Button.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding
                    Gesture="LeftClick"
                    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
            </Button.InputBindings>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

then the properties of SomeViewModel are listed in IntelliSense:

[image: intellisense]

and we can also peek or go to their definitions:

[image: peek]

Comment: Intellisense in my case does not give me the option that is actually coded there.